# C# Regex help getting multiple values

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Needing a bit help getting multiple values from a string using Regex. I am fine getting single values from the string but not multiple.

I have this string:

```
[message:USERPIN]Message to send to the user
```

I need to extract both the USERPIN and the message. I know how to get the pin:

```
 Match sendMessage = Regex.Match(message, "\\[message:[A-Z1-9]{5}\\]");
```

Just not sure how to get both of the values at the same time.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Named Groups for easy access:

```
Match sendMessage = Regex.Match(message,
    @"\[message:(?<userpin>[A-Z1-9]{5})\](?<message>.+)");

string pin = sendMessage.Groups["userpin"].Value;
string message = sendMessage.Groups["message"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = Regex.Match(message, @"\[message:([^\]]+)\](.*)");
```

After - inspect the `match.Groups` with debugger - there you have to see 2 strings that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use numbered groups.

```
Match sendMessage = Regex.Match(message, "\\[message:([A-Z1-9]{5})(.*)\\]");
string firstMatch = sendMessage.Groups[1].Value;
string secondMatch = sendMessage.Groups[2].Value;
```